# Real time search using react.js from url api

Tags: reactjs

I have been trying to create a simple Real time search application to learn React.js. I was able to simulate it using dummy data, but am having trouble when trying to do the same with a json from url/api. I don't want any onClick event, so i was using state change to search.

The url from which i will be getting data should be like

url = 'myurl/api='+searchString;

So i want the data to be collected the moment i type something. Is this possible?

Please let me know if i can do this without including any onClick event.

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/49120/) for this:

```
var SearchStock = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {searchString: '', data : []};
  },

  handleChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({searchString: e.target.value});
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var url = 'myurl/api' + searchString;
    this.serverRequest = $.get(url, function(result) {
      var quote = result;
      this.setState({quote});
    }.bind(this));
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },

  render: function() {
    var stocks = this.props.items, searchString = this.state.searchString.trim().toLowerCase();
    // var stocks = this.state.data, searchString = this.state.searchString.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (searchString.length > 0) {
      stocks = stocks.filter(function(l) {
        return l[Object.keys(l)[0]]["symbol"].toLowerCase().match(searchString);
      });
    }

    return <div >
      < input type = "text" value = {this.state.searchString} onChange = {this.handleChange} placeholder = "Type here" / >
      < ul > 
      {stocks.map(function(l) {
            return <li > {l[Object.keys(l)[0]]["name"]} < /li>
        })
      } 
      < /ul> 
    < /div>;
  }
});

var stocks = [{"F": {"symbol": "F", "name": "Ford Motor", "bidPrice": 13.41, "askPrice": 13.36}}];

// ReactDOM.render( < SearchStock />,document.getElementById('container'));
ReactDOM.render( < SearchStock items = {stocks}/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

I would appreciate any help i can get. Please let me know if there is a mistake anywhere. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example will only make the search request when the component mounts. This specific lifecycle event will only fire once, when the element is first rendered to the DOM, see: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentwillmount.

There are a number of ways you can handle this type of feature, I would recommend making the search request within the `handleChange` method. This is the first point that we have access to the data that the user has typed, so it would be ideal for your feature. I would also recommend debouncing the handler so that your not making requests for characters the user didn't actually intend to search for. Here is a good article on debouncing: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. But now that i check this. I don't think i am even able to get any data as when i hardcode the url value, it still doesn't give anything initially. I am sorry i am new to reactjs and i know this should be a very stupid mistake on my end. But i would appreciate if you can look at my fiddle and check what's wrong with the way i am fetching data from url as i feel i have followed their documentation to boot. I am expecting 'Ford Motors' in a list initially.

Comment: Here is an updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/49204/ however this code will not work. Your server is not responding with CORS headers, so requests from external servers like JSFiddle will be rejected. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://data.benzinga.com/rest/richquoteDelayed?symbols=F. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.